# Rails Associations with Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

With Rails 4.1 I can't seem to get my rails associations to work when using modules.

I have Objects within the FG module:

```
module FG
  class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_one :email
    has_one :phone
  end
end
```

And Emails in the global space:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :object, class_name: 'FG::Object'
  has_many :objects, class_name: 'FG::Object'
end
```

When I try

```
email.objects << object
```

I get the following error:

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError
can't write unknown attribute `object_id'

Am I missing something in the  association setup?

Comment: I don't think nesting models inside modules is supported

Answer (score 9):

You could write your Email code this way:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects, class_name: 'FG::Object', foreign_key: 'email_id'
end
```

This will only work if you have an `email_id` in your objects table. You can not use `has_many` and `belongs_to` referring to the same class. That would mean you have an `object_id` in the one table and an `email_id` in the other.

You could also write:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :object, class_name: 'FG::Object', foreign_key: 'object_id'
end
```

That depends on your database construction.

Answer (score 8):

I was thinking of the relationships in a conflicting way.

In order for the associations to make sense, I needed to organize them in the following way:

```
module FG
  class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    belongs_to :email
    belongs_to :phone
  end
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects, class_name: 'FG::Object'
end
```